# Move value in every 3rd cell 2 cells to the right

Tags: vba, excel

Starting from C7, I'd like to move the value in C7 two cells to the right, C7 -> E7 and F7 -> H7, etc. I have to do this until the end of the columns

My code:

```
Sub MoveCells2ToTheRight(specifiedWorksheet)

Dim lastCol As Long
With specifiedWorksheet
    lastCol = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' from column 3 to end of used columns in worksheet
    For i = 3 To lastCol
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(7, i)) Then
            .Cells(7, i).Cut
            Sheets(specifiedWorksheet).Range(.Cells(7, i + 2)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            i = i - 1
            lastCol = lastCol - 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: And where or what is the problem? What row of the code?

Comment: It seems that `specifiedWorksheet` is an object, not string, instead of `Sheets(specifiedWorksheet).Range(.Cells(7, i + 2)).Select` try just `.Cells(7, i + 2).Select`

Comment: Instead  of cut and paste you can just insert blank cells with shift to right like: `Range("C7").Resize(ColumnSize:=2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight` if there is no data in between.

Comment: Are you just wanting the value moved, or do you want to keep any formulas/formatting?

Comment: I think we may be getting off topic, as the title reads, "Move value in every 3rd cell 2 cells to the right"

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to work backwards?

Comment: I did not know that you can just insert blank cells. I replaced the cut and paste line with .Cells(7, i).Resize(ColumnSize:=2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @activexplor3 Note that I rolled back your original question. A question should always stay a question and it's better to post an answer then. So future readers can learn from it. I posted it as an answer so you can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of cut and paste you can just insert blank cells with shift to right like: `Range("C7").Resize(ColumnSize:=2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight` if there is no data in between.

```
Sub MoveCells2ToTheRight(specifiedWorksheet As Worksheet)

    Dim lastCol As Long
    With specifiedWorksheet
        lastCol = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ' from column 3 to end of used columns in worksheet
        For i = 3 To lastCol
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(7, i)) Then
                .Cells(7, i).Resize(ColumnSize:=2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                i = i - 1
                lastCol = lastCol - 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Note I recommend to specify `pecifiedWorksheet As Worksheet`.